# This array formula problem should be so easy to solve in Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My goal is to calculate the average of every 9th row starting from D3:

[image: see photo here] [example with delivery revenue in column E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMB3k.png)

What you see in this Excel sheet is the revenue earned per day of the week, split by weeks. Column A is the date of the day. Column B is the week nr. Column C is the day name. Column D is the revenue earned. Column E is the revenue earned with delivery services.

In the cells F3:F9 and G3:G9 I want to calculate the average revenue of a single day of the week seperately (i.e. all Mondays together, all Tuesdays together, etc.). Until now I used a very basic formula `=AVERAGE(D4,D13,D22,D31,D40,D49,D58,D67,D76,D85)` Now the datasheet gets larger and larger it gets very inefficient to use this manual method. Therefore I am looking for a formula that can calculate the average value of every 9th row in Column D starting from D3.

Until now I have read this example formula : `=AVERAGE(OFFSET($A$2,(ROW()-ROW($C$2))*5,,5,))` which I don't understand fully and therefore cannot get the desired result.

The following formula `=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(tbl[ID], N)=0,tbl[Value]))`is great and I understand the strategy behind it however I am not able to apply this in my data set.

Comment: _"however I am not able to apply this"_, ...Why not?  Describe what you expect, compared against what actually happens.

Comment: `=AVERAGEIF($C$3:$C$90,"monday",$D$3:$D$90)` should do?

Comment: @Rory, Thank you for your contribution. I like the way you use the name of the day as a condition. I had not thought about it. Cheers mate! :)

Comment: Seems a bit more robust than relying on which row it happens to be in. :)

Comment: Use a descriptive title. See [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=AVERAGEIF(C:C, "Monday", D:D)
```

or:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(FILTER(C:C, D:D="Monday")))
```

Answer (score 0):

without hardcoding the day names into the formulas, if the first block starts in cell A3, and you format your day names in column C as TEXT (maybe using formula like this: `=TEXT(A3,"dddd")`), then in cell G3 you can put formula like this:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF($C:$C,$C3,D:D),0)
```

then drag down to row 9